# R programming for boxplots

Tags: r, boxplot

How can I make boxplots for outcomes 1, 2, and 3 divided by minor allele count?

```
> data

     mouse.id treatment   outcome1  outcome2  outcome3 snp1 snp2 snp3 snp4 snp5 snp6 snp7 snp8
1        186         2   2427.395   240.635   526.250    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1
2        186         3   7922.080  3355.925  1786.400    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1
3        187         1   6114.500  1048.615  1375.990    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
4        187         2   2176.345   187.980   631.030    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
5        187         3   8523.140  6054.180  2932.915    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Not everyone knows what "minor allele count" is (particularly since that phrase doesn't appear in your data at all). You'll have to explain, as well as show what you've tried so far.

Comment: i need to use boxplot(split(y, g1)) where y would be the each outcome and g1 will be the each snp score

Comment: What is `y`? What is `g1`? Neither of _those_ things appear in your data either.

Comment: Y is each outcome and g1 is the each genotype score

Comment: i took out the outcome and gave a name y

Answer (score 2):

Nor sure about the boxplot question since I find that construct vastly over used and do not make an effort to learn it,  .... but the aggregation step would probably go like this:

```
aggregate(data[, c("outcome1","outcome2","outcome3")], 
           list( rowSums(data[, 6:13]) ), #construct the by-list
           FUN=mean)
#----------
  Group.1 outcome1 outcome2 outcome3
1       1 5604.662 2430.258 1646.645
2       3 5174.738 1798.280 1156.325
```

Perhaps just wrap `boxplot` around it?

```
        boxplot( ...[ ,2:4], xlab="Sum of minor alleles")
```

Nope, my testing shows me to be fairly clueless in boxplots as predicted. Wouldn't this be just as effectively displayed in a table?

Comment: Y is each outcome of three outcome(1,2,3) and g1 is each genotype score

Comment: That comment appears to come "out of the blue". There is no "Y" or "g1" in that data output , unless of course you edit you question to create some context for that comment.

Comment: i mentioned Y as one of each outcome of three treatments and g1 as each snp score(like 0,1,2)

Comment: Then you can get each outcome separately as `Yn <- aggregate(...); Yn[, 2]; Yn[,3], Yn[,4]`.